# How to check what is the Virtual Network of Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-data-factory

I need to check what is the `Virtual Network` of the `Integration Runtime` from `Azure Data Factory` with PowerShell. I know there is cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName $rgName -DataFactoryName $dfName
```

which brings me a list of IRs from my ADF, but I find it a bit limited. Is there any generic way to get the subnets and virtual networks of the IRs?

Update 1:
For my case it's a `Self Hosted Integration Runtime`.

Comment: try piping your command to `Select-Object Subnet,VNetId`

Comment: @AdminOfThings it's empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, the command just works with the Integration Runtime whose type is `Managed(Azure-SSIS)`, if it is `SelfHosted`, the command will not return the information related to the vnent and subnet.

**Note**: I test with the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.2.0) command `Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime`, what you used is the old `AzureRm`, it was deprecated and will not be updated anymore, I recommend you to use the new one, for the old `AzureRm` command `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime`, it is basically the same result, you can have a try.

*Managed Integration Runtime:*

[image]

*SelfHosted Integration Runtime:*

[image]

Comment: I updated description in the question. In my case it's Self Hosted IR. I am aware of Az but there are some requirements above me.

Comment: @MichaelK. If it is a SelfHosted one, you could not get the vnet and subnet information, all the ways to get the IR(any sdk, powershell, cli) are calling the REST API [`Integration Runtimes - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integrationruntimes/get), but you will find it returns nothing related to the vent and subnet.